# How to implement/improve/ make faster this query with joins

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please bear with me I am not skilled in SQL:

I have three tables

1) Notifications - stores all my data

2) GroupTable - Has the names of groups and related id

3) GroupUser - this table maps Uname and Udob to a group from GroupTable.

Now before I fetch records from Notifications I want to check the GroupTable for GroupID take this GroupID and look in GroupUser for all the records in this GroupID (Names,DOB as these are unique) Once I get this data I want to fetch records from Notifications table for the Names and DOB's in ascending order of the date:

So far I have the following query, it works fine just that I am not satisfied and I think this can be improved:

```
 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
   (SELECT 
        * 
    FROM Notifications 
    WHERE 
          DateToNotify < '2016-03-24' AND 
          NotificationDateFor IN 
                (SELECT gu.Name 
                 FROM GroupUser AS gu 
                 INNER JOIN GroupTable AS gt ON 
                               gu.GroupID = gt._id  AND
                               gt.GroupName = "Groupn"
                ) AND
          DOB IN 
                (SELECT gu.DOB 
                 FROM GroupUser AS gu 
                 INNER JOIN GroupTable AS gt ON 
                               gu.GroupID = gt._id AND 
                               gt.GroupName = "Groupn"
                )
     ) as T 

 ORDER BY 
      SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0) > SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)
    , SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)
```

Comment: show us the specific Foreign keys between your tables

Comment: Name and DOB are the foreign keys - unique, Name is NotificationDateFor in Notifications table.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What does substr(date,0) do? The left-most character in the date string is 1, so I guess the function treats 0 and 1 as equals, which would mean you get the string from the first character, yes? And there is no length given, so you get the string to the last character. And the string from the first to the last character is the whole string. So I'd assume substr(x,0) to do nothing. Am I wrong?

Comment: Index your search and join fields. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

Comment: Yo Der, my friend. Reading on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you would get this faster with joins instead of the IN clauses. It can be that re-writing would not even change the execution plan, because the dbms tries to access the data in the optimal way anyhow.

It seems a bit strange that you don't look for group users matching name and dob, but only ensure that there are group users matching the name and - possibly other - group users matching the dob. But as you say that the query works fine as is, okay.

EDIT: Okay, according to your comment you actually want groupuser matches on *both* name and dob. So what you are looking for would be

```
AND (NotificationDateFor, DOB) IN (SELECT gu.Name, gu.DOB FROM ...)
```

But SQLite doesn't support this beautiful syntax (Oracle is the only dbms I know of that does).

So you either join or use EXISTS.

With JOIN:

```
select distinct n.*
from notifications n
join
(
  select name, dob 
  from groupuser
  where groupid = (select _id from grouptable where groupname = 'groupn')
) as gu on n.notificationdatefor = gu.name and n.dob = gu.dob
where n.datetonotify < '2016-03-24'
order by date('now') > n.datetonotify, n.datetonotify;
```

With EXISTS:

```
select *
from notifications n
where datetonotify < '2016-03-24'
and exists
(
  select *
  from groupuser gu
  where gu.groupid = (select _id from grouptable where groupname = 'groupn')
  and gu.name = n.notificationdatefor
  and gu.dob = n.dob
)
order by date('now') > n.datetonotify, n.datetonotify;
```

Comment: Yes for me matching both Name and DOB is important, I think ive messed up there.

Comment: Thanks bro, I will try this after lunch :)